# What function can I use to check whether a string contains numbers or special chars?

Tags: php, string, function

I can't seem to find a way even after searching to check against whether a
 string contains anything except a-Z.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out PHP `preg_match`:

```
if (preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z]/', $string))) {
// to do if it contains other than letters
}
```

Hope this helps, thanks!

Comment: I'll let you know in a second!

Comment: Ah, ha, figured that was the problem!  Great success!! Thank you my friend.

Could you explain how the hell it works though?  I am pretty confused :p

Comment: Yes, yes, how do I do that exactly?  I don't seem to see a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to filter the string for a-Z , if after that string is not empty , it means it still contains something else.

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z]/", '', $string);
```

Comment: I am using regex's, do i use the substr function?  if (substr($var=="!@#$%^&*()+_/\etc...")) {
   echo "This is a regular expression";
}